# Stretch the input field

Tags: sapui5

I have a filterbar, that looks as following:

[image]

The code of the view:

```
<fb:filterGroupItems>
                    <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar.INTERNAL_GROUP" groupTitle="Contact" name="CompanyName" label="Company Name"
                        visibleInFilterBar="true">
                        <fb:control>
                            <Input type="Text"/>
                        </fb:control>
                    </fb:FilterGroupItem>
                    <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar.INTERNAL_GROUP" groupTitle="Contact" name="ContactName" label="Contact Name"
                        visibleInFilterBar="true">
                        <fb:control>
                            <Input type="Text"/>
                        </fb:control>
                    </fb:FilterGroupItem>
                    <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar.INTERNAL_GROUP" groupTitle="Contact" name="ContactTitle"
                        label="Contact Title" visibleInFilterBar="true">
                        <fb:control>
                            <Input type="Text"/>
                        </fb:control>
                    </fb:FilterGroupItem>
                    <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="Region" groupTitle="Region" name="City" label="City">
                        <fb:control>
                            <Input type="Text"/>
                        </fb:control>
                    </fb:FilterGroupItem>
                    <fb:FilterGroupItem groupName="Region" groupTitle="Region" name="Country" label="Country">
                        <fb:control>
                            <Input type="Text"/>
                        </fb:control>
                    </fb:FilterGroupItem>
                </fb:filterGroupItems>
```

As you can see, I changed the view to **iPhone 6/7..**. 
The question is, how to stretch the input field more?

Comment: have you tried "width" property for inputField?

Answer (score 0):

you can add class to your control like this

```
<Input type="Text" class="stretch" />
```

then you can add a style for stretch